# Association mapping : manytomany Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I currently have 2 Visitor and Visit entities and I made a many to many relationship but where I get stuck is how to know which entity is owner and which entity is not.

For me the table that manages everything is Visit I want to make a CRUD of its two entities for visitor no problem but for the visit entity there it complicates I manage to display the list of my visits to read them and to them delete but for edit and create sa doesn't work.

I think first of all **I have an error concerning the inversedby and mapped by of my two entities.**

But also concerning my **edit and new methods of my VisiteController.**

Entity Visite :

```
<?php
 
****
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=VisiteRepository::class)
 */
class Visite
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
 
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $libelle;
 
     
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Personne::class, mappedBy="visite")
     */
    private $personnes;
 
 
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->personnes = new ArrayCollection();
    }
 
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
 
    public function getLibelle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->libelle;
    }
 
    public function setLibelle(?string $libelle): self
    {
        $this->libelle = $libelle;
 
        return $this;
    }
 
    /**
     * @return Collection|Personne[]
     */
    public function getPersonnes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->personnes;
    }
 
    public function addPersonne(Personne $personne): self
    {
        if (!$this->personnes->contains($personne)) {
            $this->personnes[] = $personne;
            $personne->addVisite($this);
        }
 
        return $this;
    }
 
    public function removePersonne(Personne $personne): self
    {
        if ($this->personnes->contains($personne)) {
            $this->personnes->removeElement($personne);
            $personne->removeVisite($this);
        }
 
        return $this;
    }
 
 
}
```

Entity Personne/Visiteur :

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Entity;
 
use App\Repository\PersonneRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=PersonneRepository::class)
 */
class Personne
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
 
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nom;
 
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $email;
 
 
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Visite::class, inversedBy="personnes")
     */
    private $visite;
 
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->visite = new ArrayCollection();
    }
 
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
 
    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }
 
    public function setNom(?string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;
 
        return $this;
    }
 
 
    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
 
    public function setEmail(?string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;
 
        return $this;
    }
 
 
    /**
     * @return Collection|Visite[]
     */
    public function getVisite(): Collection
    {
        return $this->visite;
    }
 
    public function addVisite(Visite $visite): self
    {
        if (!$this->visite->contains($visite)) {
            $this->visite[] = $visite;
        }
 
        return $this;
    }
 
    public function removeVisite(Visite $visite): self
    {
        if ($this->visite->contains($visite)) {
            $this->visite->removeElement($visite);
        }
 
        return $this;
    }
 
}
```

When creating a new visit, it registers itself in the database but unfortunately its only insert on the visit table, I have nothing to add on the person_visit associative table.

Visit Controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/new", name="visite_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $visite = new Visite();
        $form = $this->createForm(VisiteType::class, $visite);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
 
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($visite);
            $entityManager->flush();
 
            return $this->redirectToRoute('visite_index');
        }
 
        return $this->render('visite/new.html.twig', [
            'visite' => $visite,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
 
 
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="visite_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     * @param Visite $visite
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function edit(Visite $visite, Request $request)
    {
        $personne = new Personne();
        $visite->addPersonne($personne);
 
        $form = $this->createForm(VisiteType::class, $visite);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
 
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
/*            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($visite, $personne);
            $entityManager->flush();*/
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
           /* $this->addFlash('success', 'Visite ajouté avec succès');*/
 
            return $this->redirectToRoute('visite_index');
        }
 
        return $this->render('visite/edit.html.twig', [
            'visite' => $visite,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just a sidenote, I find it better to use a reference table in which you connect both your tables so that you have 2 one-to-many relations.

Comment: If the Visite entity is the owning side, then you must have your **inversedBy** property on this entity.  I can't see where do you add your Person entity within the _new_ method. Also you can use the **ManyToMany::cascade="persist"** annotation property to automatically persist Person entities registered with your Visite entities.

Comment: Have you got an error message? Or is your related entity just not recorded in database? In the case you have no error message, you should try yo add a `dump($visit)` just before persisting entity to see if your Visit contains a Visitor.